# How do you decode the tweets.json string returned from a twitter search API request?

Tags: php, twitter-rest-api

How do you decode the `tweets.json` string returned from a twitter search API request?
I have looked through answers to similar questions. Those answers do show how to make a call, and how to display the data returned, but those don't deal with the issue of dealing with the structure of the data that is returned from the `tweets.json` API call.
Here's the code - it uses the twitter API. It requests search results.

```
<?php
require_once('../TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "......",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "......",
    'consumer_key' => "......",
    'consumer_secret' => "......"
);

$requestMethod = 'GET';

//$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json"; // I can decode output from this
//$getfield = "?screen_name=J7mbo&count=5"; // I can decode output from this
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"; // I can NOT decode output from this
$getfield = "?q=%23J7mbo&result_type=recent"; // I can NOT decode output from this

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->performRequest(); // from stackOverflow
$string = json_decode($string, $assoc = TRUE); // seems i cannot use json_decode for output from tweets.json
if ($string["errors"][0]["message"] != "")
{
    echo "twitter error message:" . $string[errors][0]["message"];
    exit();
}
foreach ($string as $items)
{
    echo "tweet text =[". $items['text']."]<br />";
}
?>
```

If I was using a twitter API timeline call, I could use `json_decode` and access `$items['text']` for each of the returned tweets
But I want to use the twitter API search call `(tweets.json). json_decode` does not properly decode the data from this search call, it only returns two empty `$items['text']`

So what's the best way to decode the `tweets.json` string returned from a twitter API request?

Comment: can you `var_dump($string)` before you try to `json_decode` it, and post the result.

Comment: Stack Overflow allows only small replies, but here it is with a lot cut out of the middle     string(68016) "{"statuses":[{"metadata":{"iso_language_code":"en","result_type":"recent"},"created_at":"Tue Jun 16 05:30:32 +0000 2015","id":610680840767418368,"id_str":"610680840767418368","text":"RT *telegraph_sport: Lay off *PaulGallen13 his explosive presser is exactly what #NRL needed #Origin *BuzzRothfield http:\/\/t.co\/2UOtKnxaI8 \u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u ..<cut>.. tities=1","count":15,"since_id":0,"since_id_str":"0"}}"

Comment: Please note that I had to replace all the @ characters with * because stackoverflow thought I was trying to notify a bunch of users. There were no * characters so you can, if you like, replace all the * in my reply with @ and you will undo.

Comment: Thanks @Augwa. I have found a way forward - see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the `$items` array and get the `text` property off of there.

```
    foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "tweet text =[". $item['text']."]<br />";
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your code. from what you've post, you're trying to get the `text` property not from the actual tweet object but from 'collection' of tweets. I presume I might have changed that and tried to fetch it from the actual tweet object. in that case, your query string looks wierd, it returns nothing. try to change it something like 'dog' and you'll see the results comign

Comment: I have tried it with other search results, and still get two empty $items['text']. You can see some of the output my reply (above) to Augwa.

Comment: I still think you're missing my point. You need to have 2 `foreach` statements. right after you do `foreach ($string as $items)` do the second loop `foreach ($items as $item)` and only then try to display the text `echo "tweet text =[". $item['text']."]<br />";` do you do like that?

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Now I get your point. The 2 `foreach` statements statements seem to work (though they produce a few extra incorrect `$item['text']` values at the end).

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMalinnkov. See the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the data I noticed that is consisted of two JSON encoded strings, named `statuses` and `search_metadata`. I extracted the `statuses` string and was able to decode it using `json_decode`.